# Create a string from a list using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to create a string separated by comma from the below given list

```
 ['D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\aaa.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\bbb.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\ccc.xlsx']
```

New string should contain only the filename like below which is separated by comma

```
'aaa.xlsx,bbb.xlsx,ccc.xlsx'
```

I have achieved this using the below code

```
n = []        
for p in input_list:
    l = p.split('\\')
    l = l[len(l)-1]
    n.append(l)
a = ','.join(n)
print(a)
```

But instead of using multiple lines of code i would like to achieve this in single line using a list comprehension or regular expression.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do a

```
main_list = ['D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\aaa.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\bbb.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\ccc.xlsx']

print([x.split("\\")[-1] for x in main_list])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['aaa.xlsx', 'bbb.xlsx', 'ccc.xlsx']
```

In case u want to get the string of this simply do a

```
print(",".join([x.split("\\")[-1] for x in main_list]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
aaa.xlsx,bbb.xlsx,ccc.xlsx
```

Another way to do the same is:

```
print(",".join(map(lambda x : x.split("\\")[-1],main_list)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
aaa.xlsx,bbb.xlsx,ccc.xlsx
```

Do see that **os.path.basename** is OS-dependent and may create problems on cross-platform scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Using `os.path.basename` with `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
import os
data = ['D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\aaa.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\bbb.xlsx', 'D:\\abc\\pqr\\123\\ccc.xlsx']
print(",".join(os.path.basename(i) for i in data))
```

**Output:**

```
aaa.xlsx,bbb.xlsx,ccc.xlsx
```